# Reducer test triggering code it shouldn't

Tags: angular, redux, karma-jasmine

In this action, we initialize a `new Student()` but only if `stuff` is passed in. In the test, `stuff` should not be passed in since that method is only initialized with the reducer.

In the test, it fails due to the `new Student()` initialization with `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'class_1.ClassActions.CLASS_INIT')`. If that `new Student()` section is removed, the test passes without any problems.

When `stuff` is logged, it is shown as `null` and no logs within the conditional block are ever actually logged out (because it doesn't officially reach that block).

Why is this test hitting this section of the code? And is there a workaround that I'm missing?

Action:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NgRedux } from 'ng2-redux';
import { IAppState } from '../../store';

import { Student } from './../../store/class';

@Injectable()
export class ClassActions {
    public static CLASS_INIT = 'CLASS_INIT';

    constructor(
        private ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>
    ) { }

public classInit(stuff) {
        this.ngRedux.dispatch({
            type: ClassActions.CLASS_INIT
        });


        if (stuff) {
             let student: Student = new Student();

             // other logic
        };
    }
}
```

Reducer

```js
import { ClassActions } from '../../actions/class';

export class Student {
    public data: any = {};
    public apps: any = [];
}


export interface IClassState {
    students: { [key: string]: Student };
}

export const INITIAL_STATE: IClassState = {
    students: {}
};

export function classStateReducer(state: IClassState = INITIAL_STATE, action: any) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case ClassActions.CLASS_INIT:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {});
     default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Reducer.spec:

```js
import { classStateReducer, INITIAL_STATE } from './class.reducer';
import { ClassActions } from './../../actions/class';

describe('Class Reducer', () => {
   it('should handle ClassActions.CLASS_INIT', () => {
        expect(
            classStateReducer(INITIAL_STATE, {
                type: ClassActions.CLASS_INIT
            })
        ).toEqual(INITIAL_STATE);
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you actually post your reducer (classStateReducer) as well?

Comment: @KwintenP Good call, I've updated the post to include the relevant part of the reducer.

Comment: Could it be that you posted the wrong failing test. In the test you posted, there is no all to the `classInit(stuff)`method. Only one to the reducer. Your reducer also doesn't call this method.

Comment: @KwintenP I wish this was the case. It seems that whenever `classStateReducer` is used, it kind of pre-runs/compiles the code in `ClassActions`. If I remove this test, no error occurs.

Comment: Since you're only using the CLASS_INIT property from that class, could you try to remove the import and use "CLASS_INIT" directly in your test. This way, that test does not longer depend on the failing class.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `it('should return the initial state', () => {
        expect(
            classStateReducer(undefined, {})
        ).toEqual(INITIAL_STATE);
    });` This still fails, even with `ClassActions` removed from the import.

Comment: I meant like this: expect(
            classStateReducer(INITIAL_STATE, {
                type: "CLASS_INIT"
            })
        ).toEqual(INITIAL_STATE);

Comment: @KwintenP Yeah, that's my next test down and it still fails if I only have that one running. I appreciate your time in trying here, I know this issue is pretty specific.

Comment: If that doesn't work, I'm afraid I'm out of options. Unless you could post the code somewhere on github.